# Dynamic Rename in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to create code to dynamically rename a table based on stored procedure parameter

```
RENAME DBNAME.SCHEMANAME.T_TABLENAME1 TO DBNAME.SCHEMANAME.T_TABLENAME1_BKP
RENAME DBNAME.SCHEMANAME.T_TABLENAME2 TO DBNAME.SCHEMANAME.T_TABLENAME2_BKP
RENAME DBNAME.SCHEMANAME.T_TABLENAME3 TO DBNAME.SCHEMANAME.T_TABLENAME3_BKP
```

```
If I pass parameter as DBNAME.SCHEMANAME.<TABLENAME> to the SP, based on that it should rename, only "_TEMP" should be removed from the table name.

Below code throws error .

  var V_RENAME = "ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS DBNAME.SCHEMANAME.T_" + INPUT_OBJECT_NAME + "RENAME TO DBNAME.SCHEMANAME.T_" + INPUT_OBJECT_NAME + "_BKP";
                 var V_CS_RENAME = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: V_RENAME} );
                 var V_RESULT_RENAME = V_CS_RENAME.execute();
```

Error

```
SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 78 unexpected 'TO'. At Statement.execute, line 43 position 51
```

Any help is appreciated .

Comment: If you are renaming in order to create a backup and then recreate the original table, you may also want to look into `CLONE` and `INSERT OVERWRITE` which would both help in maintaining table history and time-travel on the original table.  Just saying...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to add a space before RENAME.

When dynamically constructing SQL statements it’s always a good idea to write out the statement, if you are facing issues, so that you can see what is actually being created and, if necessary, run it so you can see if it works as expected.

Comment: Very likely, and you might agree with me on this:

9 out of 10 db bugs are data type issues
1 out 10 is a self inducted typo

So compare all the data types to make SURE they are the type you assume they are, and then if all of those pan out, start reading character by character until you find it ..